# How can fix Graph API error on Facebook console

Tags: flutter, facebook, dart, facebook-graph-api, flutter-dependencies

I have successfully implemented the Facebook login functionality in my Flutter App, but last some day's to getting the Graph API error on Facebook console and I have not used any Facebook functionality the related to Graph API and I'm only [login with Facebook](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_facebook_auth/versions) and use only email id, user name only.

So why am I getting this issue and how can I fix this?

https://prnt.sc/bFwm1SB7UQt-

And why I'm not able to submit app for review? Which to of permission need to allow for activate the submit button?

https://prnt.sc/Bm1Qzlt1siZH

Comment: there is a link in your first screenshot where you can appeal, did you try that one?

Comment: Yes, I have already try and appeals but not getting success ands still showing the same error even i have not used any Graph API functionality in  my App.